# Are there any signal processing libraries that implement TD-PSOLA?

Tags: matlab, audio, python, algorithms, pitch

For such a popular and old algorithm, I've had surprisingly little luck finding implementations. I've got it working in MATLAB, but am curious if any other languages have libraries containing it (python?). I've googled extensively to no avail.

Comment: can you translate the MATLAB code into C/C++?

Comment: These things seem to be secrets lol you will not find any library, I wrote it in C, python and matlab some years ago

Comment: Could you share your matlab implementation?

Answer (score -1):

When I'm looking for source code, I generally search the open repositories rather than Google.

[Try this one in C++.](https://github.com/terrykong/Phase-Vocoder/blob/master/PSOLA/PSOLA.cpp)

However, there don't seem to be many on [github,](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TD-PSOLA&type=) and sourceforge has nothing of interest.